# MYSQL SELECT most recent entry and JOIN table with multiple items per Order Number

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, max

I've searched far and wide for this answer and haven't come across any other question/solution that matches my SQL need. So with the two tables below, I want to find the most recent order_id per customer and then JOIN with another table to get the order detail (Order detail may include multiple line items)

customer table

```
customer    order_id    order_date
125         485695      1/10/2015
125         485696      2/10/2015
125         485697      3/10/2015
68          485700      6/10/2015
68          485701      12/21/2015
689         501200      8/10/2015
689         501201      8/11/2015
689         501202      8/12/2015
```

order table

```
order_id    item     qty
485695      apple    1
485695      banana   2
485697      pumpkin  1
485697      apple    1
485700      pear     1
485701      pear     1
485701      plum     2
501200      banana   1
501201      orange   2
501202      apple    3
501202      pear     2
501202      orange   1
```

The result that I am looking for will generate the following results:

```
customer    order_id    order_date  item     qty
125         485697      3/10/2015   pumpkin  1
125         485697      3/10/2015   apple    1
68          485701      6/10/2015   pear     1
68          485701      6/10/2015   plum     2
689         501202      8/12/2015   apple    3
689         501202      8/12/2015   pear     2
689         501202      8/12/2015   orange   1
```

I have tried something like this but it doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
SELECT c.customer, c.order_id, c.order_date, i.item, i.qty
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN items i ON c.order_id = i.order_id
WHERE c.order_id IN
(
SELECT max(order_id) 
           FROM customers
           GROUP BY order_id
           )
ORDER BY c.order_date DESC
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track, what you want to do is group by `customer` (id) instead of `order_id`.

```
SELECT c.customer, c.order_id, c.order_date, i.item, i.qty
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN items i ON c.order_id = i.order_id
WHERE c.order_id IN
(
SELECT max(order_id) 
       FROM customers
       GROUP BY customer
       )
ORDER BY c.order_date DESC
```

When you grouped by `order_id`, each individual `order_id` got included inside the `SELECT max(order_id)` query, thus every item order was included in the `WHERE` clause selecting all orders.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you know if there is a quicker way to get the results I'm looking for? Each of these tables have a fairly large amount of data so something quicker would be ideal. It doesn't necessarily need to be done in the method I was aiming for, it was just the first one that made somewhat sense. Thanks for the help! @Cariboutis

Comment: I'm not sure of a quicker way to do it. You could group the customer and acquire the max order_id in the `FROM` statement of the customers table, but that may not be any faster.